# Wordpress Loop displaying Multiple Songs on page to download

Tags: php, wordpress, download

I have a page which runs a loop displaying a few songs. These songs can be clicked through to and listened to on another page.

I have created a PHP script that sits in the same folder as the file. The script directly downloads the file, see below:

```
    <?php $file = $_GET['file'];
header ("Content-type: octet/stream"); \
header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$file.";");
header ("Content-Length: ".filesize($file)); readfile($file); exit;
?>
```

Then in the page-template I have an anchor tag to download the file which looks like this:

```
<a class="black-button" href="http://localhost/sitename/media/direct_download.php?file=">Download</a>
```

I am after something that will automatically add each file to the anchor tag rather then hardcoding each one..

My PHP is not the best and I am soo confused.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the Glob function.  You can read more about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

```
foreach (glob("*.mp3") as $filename) {
  echo "<a class='black-button' href='http://localhost/sitename/media/direct_download.php?file=$filename'>Download $filename</a><br/>";
}
```

This will make a loop looking for all mp3 files in the same directory in which the PHP file is executed and will output the files as links.